# How to interpret those two uncompressed zlib samples?

Tags: python, reverse-engineering, zlib, specifications

I'm trying to learn how to read specifications. Let's see what one gets after trying to compress: 1) an empty buffer and 2) an exclamation mark:

```
>>> zlib.compress(b'', 0)
b'x\x01\x01\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x01'
>>> zlib.compress(b'!', 0)
b'x\x01\x01\x01\x00\xfe\xff!\x00"\x00"'
```

So far I found that `x\x01` is the magic format telling us that we're looking at an uncompressed zlib sample. Then there's `\x01` that I can't interpret (I guess it means "uncompressed block follows") and `\x01\x00` that seems to be the buffer length, after which there's `\xfe\xff` (which seems to decrease further if I add more bytes), then the data and four bytes that seem to be the Adler checksum.

Now, my question is: how can I find what the third byte and the next four ones mean?

Also, is there a way to skip Adler checksum and still produce something that `zlib.decompress()` can process? In other words, is there a shorter minimal Zlib buffer sample?

Answer (score 2):

The format of the zlib wrapper can be found in [RFC 1950](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt), and the format of the deflate compressed data that it wraps can be found in [RFC 1951](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt).

The `x\x01` is the zlib header, and the `\x00\x00\x00\x01` at the end is the Adler-32 check. In the middle is a single stored deflate block, which is identified by `\x01`, which is a three-bit header starting at the least significant bit that is a one, indicating this is the last deflate block in the stream, and the next two bits are zeros, indicating a stored block. The remaining five bits are fill bits to bring the stream to a byte boundary. Then the `\x00\x00\xff\xff` is the two-byte length of the stored block contents (0), followed by the one's complement of the length as an error check. That's it for the empty stored block.

For the stored block with an exclamation mark, the differences are that the length is one (note that the length is in little-endian order), followed by the complement, and then the exclamation mark itself. The Adler-32 check value corresponds to the message with one byte that is an exclamation mark.

You can use the `zlib.compressobj` can be given `wbits` equal to `-15` to request a raw deflate stream with no zlib wrapper.